# How to avoid O(N^2) when comparing elements from 2 lists?

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I have 2 lists with same Object type.

```
List A [ foo, bar, moo, woo, pee ]

List B [ bar, woo ]
```

I want to compare those 2 lists and if the name matches, 
set its property to true.

For instance,

```
if(ListA[1].name.equals(ListB[0].name)) { //match name 'bar' and 'bar'
    ListA[1].hasSameName = true;
}
```

something like that.

I can write O(N^2) solution.

```
for(Talent checkedTalent : ListA) {
    for(Talent filteredTalent : ListB) {
        if( checkedTalent.Id.equals(filteredTalent.Id) ) {
            filteredTalent.isSelected = true;   
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done in more efficient way?

Comment: Quick but stupid: sort and compare.

Comment: order matters? can there be dupes? because in these cases the trivial might even not be true. if it does not matter and no dupes, I advise using a Set and not a List.

Comment: @amit: There would be no duplicate values and order does not matter.

Comment: then I vote for the suggested hash solutions, but I still think (at least for readability) using a Set is more approppriate then a List (unless it is critical performance issue and the insertion overhead cannot be taken)

Comment: @amit: I agree too, using Set seems better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use hashing for an O(n) solution (assuming an efficient hash implementation):

```
Set<String> ids = new HashSet<String>(ListA.size());
for(Talent checkedTalent : ListA) {
    ids.add(checkedTalent.Id);
}
for(Talent filteredTalent : ListB) {
    if (ids.contains(filteredTalent.Id)) {
        filteredTalent.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: HashSet has a constructor that accepts any Collection as an argument, which will keep you from having to implement the first loop (although you still incur the overhead). Oh - I see that you mapping each Talent to an Id. I didnt' realize that. Nevermind this comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution has that time-complexity because for each element from `ListA`, you must check *all* of `ListB` (again). You could reduce to O(n) if you could somehow do an O(1) lookup on `ListB` for the current element from `ListA`. One data structure that you can use to do that is a `Map`.

So, if you build a `Map` out of one of the lists and traverse the other, looking up each element in the `Map` to see if there is match, you can reduce the overall time complexity to O(n) - at the cost of O(n) space.

For example:

```
Map<String, Talent> map = new HashMap<String, Talent>();

for(Talent t : ListA)
{
    // traverse each talent into
    // a map element.
    map.put(t.id, t); 
}

for(Talent t : ListB)
{
    if(map.containsKey(t.id))
    {
        t.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Could* be `Set`, doesn't *have* to be, as the example above demonstrates. The overall time complexity is the same - however, I will concede that the answers using the `Set` are cleaner.

Comment: Doesn't work like that with a `HashMap`, there is no `add()` method.  You would have to use `put(t.id, null)` and then check if `map.keySet().containsKey(t.id)`.  Probably what you want is a `Set` instead of a `Map`.

Comment: Ugh! That's what I get for hanging around SO when I should be sleeping :/ Sorry @John, thanks @amit, @aroth. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Sort then (2*(n log n)) and then walk your way along each list (2*n).

Answer (score 1):

For some inspiration on how to do this more efficiently, read up on how a SQL join can be implemented, namely a [Nested loop join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_loop_join), a Nested loop join with a b-tree index (sort one and binary search through it for each element in the other), a [Merge join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join), or a [Hash join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join).  Same concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Set from the first List:

```
Set mySet = new HashSet(listA);
```

Now you loop over listB:

```
for(Object foo : listB)
    if(mySet.contains(foo))
        foo.isSelected = true
```

This is O(n * lg n), I think, but I'm not going to provide a proof. :)